# Adding brackets to regex breaks it in ruby String#scan method

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an app which uses ruby 1.8.6 and rails 2.2.2 (please don't talk about how i need to update this).

I have a text doc of server accesses which i'm scraping data out of.  The lines are like

```
line1 = "93.97.151.194 - - [14/Nov/2013:20:13:30 +0000] \"GET /assets/dvd_files/pdfs/4139/DSB%20Guitar%20%E2%80%94%20medium.pdf HTTP/1.1\" 200 21172 \"http://www.mysite.co.uk/c/1267-ks3/131936-inspira-pops/134541-don-t-stop-believin-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36\""

line2 = "93.97.151.194 - - [14/Nov/2013:20:13:30 +0000] \"HEAD /assets/dvd_files/pdfs/4139/DSB%20Guitar%20%E2%80%94%20medium.pdf HTTP/1.1\" 200 21172 \"http://www.mysite.co.uk/c/1267-ks3/131936-inspira-pops/134541-don-t-stop-believin-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36\""
```

I was collecting the first path part with this regex:

```
#this works fine for the GET case
path = line1.scan(/\"GET\s[^\s]+/).first
=> "\"GET /assets/dvd_files/pdfs/4139/DSB%20Guitar%20%E2%80%94%20medium.pdf"
```

So far so good.  But some of the lines have HEAD as the method, so i modified my regex to say `(GET|HEAD)` instead of just `GET`.  Now, it just returns the method name (GET or HEAD), without the path.  eg

```
path = line1.scan(/\"(GET|HEAD)\s[^\s]+/).first
=> ["GET"]
```

Now i get an array back, instead of a string:  the results of the scan (without calling first, is a 2-d array:

```
path = line1.scan(/\"(GET|HEAD)\s[^\s]+/)
=> [["GET"]]
```

I don't understand why this isn't working. Is this a peculiarity of the scan method? Can anyone set me straight?  thanks

EDIT
Using String#match instead of #scan seems to work:

```
path = line1.match(/\"(GET|HEAD)\s[^\s]+/).to_s
=> "\"GET /assets/dvd_files/pdfs/4139/DSB%20Guitar%20%E2%80%94%20medium.pdf"
```

Can anyone explain why match works and scan doesn't here?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for `scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-scan)? *"If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group."*

Comment: aha - no.  "RTFM NOOB LOL" as the classic newsgroup comment goes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-scan) will return an array of matches, where each match is an array, containing the values of all capturing groups for that match.

In Regex, a capturing group is an expression enclosed in parenthesis.

In your case, since you have `(GET|HEAD)` in your expression, that's considered a capture and is returned.

To illustrate this, let's modify the Regex to be `/(GET|HEAD)\s([^\s]+)/` (I also made the `[^\s]+` part a capturing group). For your `line1` variable this will return:

```
[["GET", "/assets/dvd_files/pdfs/4139/DSB%20Guitar%20%E2%80%94%20medium.pdf"]]
```

(one match with two capture groups in it).

#### Fix

[The documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-scan) states that:

> If the pattern contains no groups, each individual result consists of the matched string, $&. If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.

If you want to have `GET|HEAD` enclosed in parenthesis, but do not want it to be considered a capturing group, use `?:`, as follows: `/(?:GET|HEAD)\s[^\s]+/`. This will tell the Regex engine that the parenthesis just enclose a part of the expression, but it isn't a capturing group.

Here it is in action: http://ideone.com/0Ri1Uv

Answer (score 1):

example of scan usage

```
line1.scan(/\"(GET|HEAD)\s[^\s]+(.*)/) do |req, rest| 
   p req
   p rest
end

# will output

"GET"
" HTTP/1.1\" 200 21172 \"http://www.mysite.co.uk/c/1267-ks3/131936-inspira-pops/134541-don-t-stop-believin-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36\""
```